# Creating a new random operation in computation graph of Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

How can I create a new random operator (something like tf.random_normal) which is part of the graph? I want to add Cauchy random variable to the output of one layer of my network.
I found  tf.contrib.distributions.Cauchy, but how can I make it work inside a layer ( as we have with random_normal)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. I advise you to read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It will help you get better/more answers to your questions

Comment: What do you mean by "inside a layer"?

Comment: @walkerlala inbetween the layers. Like add a random noise to the output of one layer and then pass it to another layer.